# Symfony 2.8 doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, oop, doctrine

I have an simple Abstract ApiController (extends from Controller) class, where i handle Auth.

```
protected function handleAuth(){
    $login = $this->request->getUser();
    $password = $this->request->getPassword();

    $user = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    if (!$user)
    {
        return $this->sendResponse(array('msg'=>'User not found'),404);
    }
    $user = $user[0];

    if(!password_verify($data['password'], $user->getUserPass())){
        return $this->sendResponse(array('msg'=>'Invalid credentials'),401);
    }

    return true;
}
```

But it throws an erorr with getting doctrine in my Abstract Controller:

```
Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php at line 391
```

How can i get doctrine in my Abstract class?

Comment: Did you register the abstract ApiController as a service?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `$this->get(something.or.other)`, your container needs to extend `ContainerAware`, which it will automatically do if you simply `extends Controller`.

As of 2.8, `ContainerAware` is deprecated in favor of `ContainerAwareTrait`, but if your abstract controller simply extends Controller, then you don't need to worry yourself with that.

Comment: but this is a problem, my abstract class extends Controller

Comment: Ah, please try using `$this->container->get(...)` instead.

Comment: it throws an error "$this->container = null",

but I don't understand why, because

`dump(get_class_methods(get_class($this)));`
show get() method

Comment: Sorry, it looks like the error is somewhere outside the code you have posted then. If the project is open-source, I could take a closer look for you.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I can't=(